Conditional expectation taking the value infinite.
I would like to show this:

Assume that $X$ is a non-negative random variable on $(\Omega,
 \mathcal{A}, P)$. Let $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{A}$ be a sub
sigma-algebra. Pick a version of the conditional expectation
$E[X|\mathcal{F}]$. I would like to show that
$$1_{\{\omega: X(\omega)=\infty\}}(\omega)\le 1_{\{\omega:
 E[X|\mathcal{F}](\omega)=\infty\}}(\omega), a.s.$$

The way I was thinking of showing this is showing that $P(\{\omega: X(\omega)=\infty\}\cap\{\omega:
 E[X|\mathcal{F}](\omega)<\infty\})=0.$ I have tried using the definition of conditional expectation, but that didn't take me to the end.
Do you see how to solve this?
Note: The problem is originally from the exercise below, but I have rewritten it a little, because it does not make sense that a set is contained in another set a.s.


Is the conditional expectation defined as usual? If so, the random variable X would have to be integrable, and so the set ${\omega : X(\omega) = +\infty }$ has to have measure 0, which means that the indicator on the left is a.s. equal to 0. This means that what you want to show is trivially always true.

@vectorSpace Good point, this is from an exercise that does not specify that. So I am trying to see if it holds for the general definition where $X$ may not be integrable.

The definition of conditional expectation is a RV measurable with respect to ${\cal F}$ satisfying
$$\int_A X dP = \int_A E[X | {\cal F} ]dP$$
for all $A\in {\cal F}$.
Let $A_n = \{ E[X|{\cal F}] \le n\}$. Then
$$\int_{A_n} X d P \le n P(A_n)< \infty.$$
This implies that on $A_n$ $X<\infty$, possibly on a subset of measure zero. Therefore on $\{E[X|{\cal F}]<\infty\}= \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ we have that $X<\infty$, possibly except on a subset of measure zero, which is equivalent to the statement you wish to prove.

Notice that if $\mu(\{\omega: X(\omega) = +\infty\}) = 0$ then then the corresponding indicator function is a.s. equal to 0, and so the claim holds. This is necessarily the case if $X$ is integrable, and so for the usual definition of conditional expectation, which demands integrability, this is as far as the argument needs to go.
If we assume that we are interested in the generalised conditional expectation, ie
$$\hat{E}[X|\mathcal{F}] = \sup_N E[X \wedge N |\mathcal{F}] $$
then, if $\mu(\{X=+\infty\} ) = 0$, we use the same argument as above. Otherwise,
$$\hat{E}[X|\mathcal{F}] \ge \hat{E}[X\mathbb{1}_{\{X=+\infty}\}|\mathcal{F}] = +\infty \hspace{2mm} a.s.$$
This suggests that $\mathbb{1}_{\{\hat{E}[X|\mathcal{F}] = \infty\}} = 1 \hspace{2mm} a.s.$, and so once again, what we want to show holds.

Thank you, very much!, but how do you get $\hat{E}[X\mathbb{1}{{X=+\infty}}|\mathcal{F}] = +\infty$ a.s.? If $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{A}$, isn't then $\hat{E}[X\mathbb{1}{{X=+\infty}}|\mathcal{F}] =X\mathbb{1}_{{X=+\infty}}$?, which is not necessarily $\infty$ a.s.?
